# DirectorySearcher can't find fax property

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory

I am useing `DirectorySearcher` to find details about the current user.

```
UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.Current;
DirectoryEntry? user = u.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(user);
ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[]
{
    "fax", "displayName", "streetAddress", "department", "telephoneNumber"
});
var entry = ds.FindOne();
```

"fax" is not in the `Property` collection

I confirmd that the value is set in the AD.

Powershell displays it correctly

```
PS C:\Users\Henrik Halbritter> get-aduser "Henrik Halbritter" -Property "fax" | select -Property fax

fax
---
0123456
```

Comment: The PowerShell cmdlets use more user-friendly names. As mentioned in the answer below, the actual AD attribute is [`facsimileTelephoneNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-facsimiletelephonenumber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `fax`, try `facsimileTelephoneNumber`.  AD property names can be very inconsistent in the way they are referenced.

Comment: Is there a place to look up the property names?

Comment: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/attributes-all) and [this](http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes.htm).